# Optimizing storage of vectors of dynamically sized vectors

Tags: c++, caching, vector

I've encountered this problem pattern multiple times in some work I'm doing, and I'm wondering if a known solution exists.

It's simple: I have a vector of elements, which in turn are vectors of some dynamic size. I know the size of the inner vectors will be relatively small (i.e. in the order of 10s of items, in the average case), but there will be a lot of them.

I can solve this naively:

```
vector<vector<item>> vss;
```

Using this approach memory allocations in the inner vector will be all over the place. Iterating over all elements within `vss` will be a mess cache-wise, and this may cause me performance problems.

I'm thinking this could be solved using some sort of linked list-structure with multiple heads within the same block of memory.

Assuming that the size of the inner vectors can't be predetermined, is there a way to construct and fill `vss` such that iterating over the elements is not going to be a cache disaster?

Thank you.

Comment: If you think this has memory allocations "all over the place", I can assure you a traditional linked list will be no better, and highly probable it will be *worse*. As it stands now you have effectively a table of pointers to dynamic rows. if the over all pool size is generally the same, you *may* get away with managing your own *allocator*, but most standard libs already sub allocate for you, and fairly efficiently, so I don't see a huge win there.

Comment: WhozCraig , I realize using a traditional linked list would be even worse. What I had in mind was allocating a large block of memory and keeping the linked list**s** within that block (and reallocating and moving if necessary).

Comment: Exactly, which is where my suggesting you may be able to accomplish that somewhat transparently using a custom *allocator* and keeping your layout, but instead using `std::vector<std::vector<Item,SomeAllocator>>` where your allocator pulls from a pool of memory you manage yourself. You may not have to reinvent *too* much of the wheel.

Comment: As a half-baked but potentially easy-win alternative to WhozCraig's custom allocator suggestion, and depending on many, many things - how and when you insert/erase elements, whether it's worthwhile repacking given the amount of post-vector-population processing etc. - it might work out having a `vector<item> data` and `vector<size_t> index` such that `data[index[i]+j]` was equivalent to your old `vss[i][j]` - you could easily create a wrapper class so the `[i][j]` notation still worked....

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my current, but hopefully temporary, solution. Instead of filling up `vss` directly, I use a temporary vector of pairs:

`vector<pair<size_t, item>> temporaries;`

, which denotes that some item should be inserted at a specific index. From here I count up the number of entries per index, allocate a single block of memory to hold the items, and move the data. Some additional vectors are used for book-keeping (i.e. number of items per index, and their starting position).